# Read file line by line ARDUINO

Tags: string, arduino-uno, sd-card

I'm doing a function for my project in Arduino, for read line by line a file (log.txt) stored in a SdCard, and send (every line) it over Bluetooth.
The format of log is:

```
020/5/25 18:15:46|0*26.0 34.5
020/5/25 18:16:46|0*26.0 34.2
```

I need to cut every line in two string (delimiter = '|'), and then send to an Android App (over BLE)
I use the next library for cut every line in two strings:https://www.somosioticos.com/archivos/separador.zip
And my code is:

```
void R_SdCard(){
   File printFile;
   String Buffer_Read_Line = "";
   String Sub_String_A = "";
   String Sub_String_B = ""; 

   printFile = SD.open("Log.txt", FILE_READ);

   while(printFile.available()){
     Buffer_Read_Line=printFile.readStringUntil("\r\n");
     Sub_String_A=S.separa(Buffer_Read_Line,'|',0);
     Sub_String_B=S.separa(Buffer_Read_Line,'|',1);
     HM10.println(Sub_String_A);
     delay(3000);
     HM10.println(Sub_String_B);
     delay(3000);
   }
   printFile.close();
}
```

For string Sub_String_A, the output is:

```
020/5/25 18:15:46
```

For string Sub_String_B, the output is:

```
18:15:46
```

These is correct, but only read one line of the file... I need read every line in this file.
How can I do it??? 
Thx in advance!

Comment: `readStringUntil("\r\n")` Maybe the file does not have `\r\n` and only `\n`?

Comment: Sorry... The code has a problem here: `readStringUntil("\r\n")`. The rigth code is: `readStringUntil('\r\n')` and your proposal to change it to: `readStringUntil('\n')` ,gives the same result...

Comment: Maybe I must to use seek() or position(), to set the position in the file, but I have no idea how do it!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution.
The code is:

```
void R_SdCard(){   
  File printFile;
  String Buffer_Read_Line = "";
  String Sub_String_A = "";
  String Sub_String_B = ""; 
  int LastPosition=0;

  printFile = SD.open("Log.txt");
  int totalBytes = printFile.size();

  while (printFile.available()){
    for(LastPosition=0; LastPosition<= totalBytes; LastPosition++){
      char caracter=printFile.read();
      Buffer_Read_Line=Buffer_Read_Line+caracter;
      if(caracter==10 ){            //ASCII new line
        Serial.println(Buffer_Read_Line);
        Sub_String_A=S.separa(Buffer_Read_Line,'|',0);
        Sub_String_B=S.separa(Buffer_Read_Line,'|',1);
        HM10.println(Sub_String_A);
        HM10.println(Sub_String_B);
        Buffer_Read_Line="";      //string to 0
      }
    }
  }
  printFile.close();
}
```

I hope this code is helpful for those who need read data from a file!
Greetings!